# How to allow POST restful webservice calls with Django Piston and CSRF protection?

Tags: django, django-piston

I'm new to django-piston and cannot get POST webservice calls to work due to Django's CSRF protection.  How do I allow webservice calls to bypass the CSRF protection and still allow the rest of the webpages to keep them?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution: https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/issue/82/post-requests-fail-when-using-django-trunk, credit goes to Brian Zambrano.

I find it a bit annoying that this is two years old, a patch has been created and still not merged into the latest source.

To fix it apply the patch to your piston/resource.py file by adding **self.csrf_exempt = getattr(self.handler, 'csrf_exempt', True)** like below:

```
         self.handler = handler()
+        self.csrf_exempt = getattr(self.handler, 'csrf_exempt', True)

         if not authentication:
             self.authentication = NoAuthentication()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that? CSRF is a simple domain check ... but if you really really need it, the answer is in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views

Comment: CSRF is not as simple as a domain check.